# C++ mutex locking error

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, c++14

I am working a thread pool with work stealing capabilities, but whenever the program tries to lock the mutex in the work queue, I get an exception error.

I've tried the program on both Windows Visual Studio 2015 and Ubuntu 14.04 and both produce a run time exception.

I've tested the work queue extensively by itself and can't reproduce the error. If I comment out the try_steal function, I do not run into any errors. Lastly I've replace std::mutex with std::recursive_mutex and I still get the same error.

I thought the exception occurred during the deconstruction of the thread pool, namely one thread trying to read the work queue of another thread that has been destroyed already. But even after the introduction of an infinite loop before the end of the program, the same exception occurred.

I was wondering if there was something else I was not thinking to check, below you will find the relevant code and the VS 2015  and Linux call stacks.

Thanks for all your help.

Windows Call stack:

> msvcp140d.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * mtx, const xtime * target)
>           msvcp140d.dll!_Mtx_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * mtx)
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * _Mtx)
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_Mutex_base::lock() 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::lock_guard::lock_guard(std::mutex & _Mtx)
>       thread_pool_test.exe!work_stealing_queue::try_steal(function_wrapper & res)
>       thread_pool_test.exe!thread_pool_steal::pop_task_from_other_thread_queue(function_wrapper & task)
>       thread_pool_test.exe!thread_pool_steal::run_pending_task()
>       thread_pool_test.exe!thread_pool_steal::worker_thread(unsigned int my_index_) 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_Invoker_pmf_pointer::_Call(void (unsigned int) * _Pmf, thread_pool_steal * && _Arg1, int && <_Args2_0>) Line 1373  C++
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::invoke(void (unsigned int) * && _Obj, thread_pool_steal * && <_Args_0>, int && <_Args_1>) 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_LaunchPad,std::default_delete > > >::_Execute<0,1,2>(std::tuple & _Tup, std::integer_sequence __formal) 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_LaunchPad,std::default_delete > > >::_Run(std::_LaunchPad,std::default_delete > > > * _Ln) 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_LaunchPad,std::default_delete > > >::_Go() 
>       thread_pool_test.exe!std::_Pad::_Call_func(void * _Data) 
>       ucrtbased.dll!0fa27e48()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ucrtbased.dll]
>       ucrtbased.dll!0fa27b8b()
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12 ()
>       ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8 ()
>       ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8 ()

Linux call stack:

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff6f5d700 (LWP 4395)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6f5d700 (LWP 4395)]
__GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0)
    at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66
66  ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x0)
    at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:66
#1  0x0000000000401f53 in __gthread_mutex_lock (__mutex=0x50)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/gthr-default.h:748
#2  0x00000000004023ba in std::mutex::lock (this=0x50)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:135
#3  0x000000000040370a in std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard (
    this=0x7ffff6f5cd10, __m=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:377
#4  0x00000000004030fa in work_stealing_queue::try_steal (this=0x0, 
    res=...) at Source.cpp:250
#5  0x00000000004032c8 in thread_pool_steal::pop_task_from_other_thread_queue (this=0x7fffffffdac0, task=...) at Source.cpp:302
#6  0x00000000004035e4 in thread_pool_steal::run_pending_task (
    this=0x7fffffffdac0) at Source.cpp:358
#7  0x00000000004031ba in thread_pool_steal::worker_thread (
    this=0x7fffffffdac0, my_index_=0) at Source.cpp:283
#8  0x000000000040d3d4 in std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_pool_steal::*)(unsigned int)>::operator()<int, void>(thread_pool_steal*, int&&) const (
    this=0x62af78, __object=0x7fffffffdac0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:569
#9  0x000000000040cec9 in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_pool_steal::*)(unsigned int)> (thread_pool_steal*, int)>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (this=0x62af68)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1700
#10 0x000000000040c87f in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_pool_steal::*)(unsigned int)> (thread_pool_steal*, int)>::operator()() (
    this=0x62af68) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1688
#11 0x000000000040c4ea in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (thread_pool_steal::*)(unsigned int)> (thread_pool_steal*, int)> >::_M_run() (this=0x62af50) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:115
#12 0x00007ffff78f7e40 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#13 0x00007ffff7bc4182 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff6f5d700)
    at pthread_create.c:312
#14 0x00007ffff735e47d in clone ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

Code:

```
class work_stealing_queue
{
 private:
 typedef function_wrapper data_type;
 std::deque<data_type> the_queue;
 mutable std::mutex the_mutex;

bool empty() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
    return the_queue.empty();
}

bool try_steal(data_type& res)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(the_mutex);
    if (the_queue.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    res = std::move(the_queue.back());
    the_queue.pop_back();
    return true;
}
};


class thread_pool_steal
{

typedef function_wrapper task_type;

std::atomic_bool done;
threadsafe_queue<task_type> pool_work_queue;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<work_stealing_queue> > queues;
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

static thread_local work_stealing_queue* local_work_queue;
static thread_local unsigned int my_index;

join_threads joiner;


bool pop_task_from_other_thread_queue(task_type& task)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i<queues.size(); ++i)
    {
        unsigned const index = (my_index + i + 1) % queues.size();
        if (queues[index]->try_steal(task))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public:

thread_pool_steal() : done(false), joiner(threads)
{
    unsigned const thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    try
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i<thread_count; ++i)
        {
            queues.push_back(std::unique_ptr<work_stealing_queue>(std::make_unique<work_stealing_queue>()));
            threads.push_back(std::move(std::thread(&thread_pool_steal::worker_thread, this, i)));

        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        done = true;
        throw;
    }
};

~thread_pool_steal()
{
    done = true;
};
```

Comment: probably has something to do with threadsafe initialization of a static mutex object. I am struggling with a similar problem now. Are you compiling/linking with -pthread?

Comment: @iggy Yes when I compile on a linux computer, I use pthreads. Thanks for the tip, I will look into if error has to do with the static initialization.

Comment: Actually it says `work_stealing_queue::try_steal (this=0x0`, so you have a null object

Comment: compile it with `-fsanitize=address` and see what you get

Comment: Compiled with the following g++ -std="c++14" -g -fsanitize=address Source.cpp -o test -lpthread I get

Comment: ==3103==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000060 (pc 0x7f243995f414 sp 0x7f2436e3db70 bp 0x7f2436e3db90 T1)

Comment: #0 0x7f243995f413 in pthread_mutex_lock (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0xa413)

Comment: #1 0x402762 in __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/gthr-default.h:748

Comment: #2 0x402f7f in std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:135

Comment: #3 0x4052ac in std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/4.9/mutex:377

Comment: #4 0x404746 in work_stealing_queue::try_steal(function_wrapper&) /home/kc1491/Desktop/Untitled Folder/Source.cpp:250

Comment: AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ??:0 pthread_mutex_lock
Thread T1 created by T0 here:
    #0 0x7f243a4eec4a in __interceptor_pthread_create (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.1+0x23c4a)
    #1 0x7f243a206f96 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)()) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0xb7f96)

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and evaluating what's returned?

Comment: @JoshuaWaring, I have no experience working with Try Catch blocks in C++. I tried to catch the exception as you requested, but was unsuccessful. Here is what I have tried
  try
  {
   the_mutex.lock();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
   std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  and 

  try {
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < queues.size(); ++i)
   {
    unsigned const index = ((my_index + i + 1) % queues.size());
    if (queues[index]->try_steal(task))
    {
     return true;
    }
   }
   return false;
    

    
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
   std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

Comment: @JoshuaWaring If that is not the correct way to use a Try catch block I would appreciate any tips and advice.

Comment: try{ 
    // All your code
catch(std::exception ex){
   std::cout << ex.what();
}
Put all the code of the function inside of one try, catch. Anything that occurs inside of the try will be caught.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/
Reference

Comment: For a future reference, I am quite sure that this code is from [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition) (listing 9.8). I have exactly the same issue with gcc-8.2.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, "the_mutex" must be initialized before calling pthread_mutex_lock().
See Unix Network Programming Vol.1 2nd Ed. (W. Richard Stevens) p.626.
It says "If a mutex variable is statically allocated, we must initialize it to the constant PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER." It will look like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t the_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this error is occurring because std::vector is not thread safe. 
While the main thread is adding to the the vector of work_stealing_queue,queues, the newly spawn threads call queues.size(). My guess is that the size() function is being incremented before the newest work_stealing_queue in queues is ready. The solution is to create two separate loops, one to create all the work_stealing_queue in queues and another to run the threads with the function worker_thread.

```
for(auto i=0;i<thread_count;++i)
            {
               queues.push_back(std::unique_ptr<work_stealing_queue>  (std::make_unique<work_stealing_queue>()));
            }

for(auto i=0;i<thread_count;++i) // Seperate becuse std::vector is not thread safe and causes issues when size() is used
            {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(&thread_pool_steal::worker_thread,this,i));
            }
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work! I struggled with what I think is the same code from Anthony Williams' book before I found your answer here.